# cufft is adding random data to results

Tags: c, cuda, cufft

I made a quick program to make sure I could use the cufft library correctly. When I run a batch size of "1" I get the result I expect. However, as I increase the batch size, I get what appears to be random bytes at the end of my data buffer. If the batch size is 2, the last three entries are noise. If the batch size is 3, I get noise in the last six entries at the end of the buffer, as well as in the three entries at the end of what should be the results from the second of the three transforms in the batch.

Example of bad data at the end of the results of the second transform in a batch:

`7.680291   1.411589` <- good data
`7.748493   1.062853`
`7.797380   0.710554`
`7.826757   0.355854`
`-436781318144.000000   -436781318144.000000` <- start of bad results
`5349828096.000000  5000401408.000000`
`5511789568.000000  4813803008.000000`
`5664713728.000000  4619900416.000000`
<- end of output

Code:

```
#define NX 1024
#define BATCH 4

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftComplex *deviceData;
    cufftComplex *hostData;
    FILE* output;
    char fileName[256];

    int i, j;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceData, NX * BATCH * sizeof(cufftComplex));
    hostData = (cufftComplex*)malloc(NX * BATCH * sizeof(cufftComplex);

    //Initalize array with a real sin wave, increasing the frequency of the wave for each transform in the batch (indexed by "j")
    for (j = 0; j < BATCH; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < NX; i++)
        {
            hostData[i + j*BATCH].x = sin(i*(j+1) / (float)10);
            hostData[i + j*BATCH].y = 0;
        }
    }

    cudaMemcpy(deviceData, hostData, NX * BATCH * sizeof(cufftComplex), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cufftPlan1d(&plan, NX, CUFFT_C2C, BATCH);
    cufftExecC2C(plan, deviceData, deviceData, CUFFT_FORWARD);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(hostData, deviceData, NX * BATCH * sizeof(cufftComplex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cufftDestroy(plan);
    cudaFree(deviceData);

    output = fopen("outputFile.txt", "w");

    //Write one file for each transform in the batch
    for (j = 0; j < BATCH; j++)
    {
        memset(fileName, '\0', 256);
        sprintf(fileName, "outputFile_%d.txt", j);
        output = fopen(fileName, "w");
        for (i = 0; i < NX; i++)
            fprintf(output, "%f\t%f\n", hostData[i + j*BATCH].x, hostData[i + j*BATCH].y);
        fclose(output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you're mixing up the usage of BATCH and NX to index into your data sets.

I think your final fprintf line should be this instead of what you have:

`fprintf(output, "%f\t%f\n", hostData[i + j*NX].x, hostData[i + j*NX].y);`

Likewise you need to change your data setup lines from

`hostData[i + j*BATCH]...`

to

`hostData[i + j*NX]...`

(2 instances.)

And while we're at it, this line does not compile for me, it's missing a close parenthesis:

```
hostData = (cufftComplex*)malloc(NX * BATCH * sizeof(cufftComplex);
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I was really hoping I had done something idiotic like that, and I appreciate you looking at the code with fresh eyes.